# When adding a custom block moodle shows [[pluginname]]

Tags: php, moodle

I am creating a custom block for moodle and when I try to add it into a page is shown as follows:

[image: How moodle name is shown]

Instead of a specified name.

The `version.php` file has these:

```
$plugin->component = 'block_userlist';
$plugin->version = 2019050316;
$plugin->requires = 2018120300;
```

And the block is defines as:

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class block_userlist extends block_base {
    public function init() {
        $this->title = get_string('userlist', 'block_userlist');
    }
    // The PHP tag and the curly bracket for the class definition 
    // will only be closed after there is another function added in the next section.

    public function get_content() {
        global $DB;

        // if ($this->content !== null) {
        //   return $this->content;
        // }

        $user = $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT COUNT(*) as total_users FROM {user};');

        $this->content         =  new stdClass;
        $this->content->text  .= 'The content of our ';
        $this->content->text  .= html_writer::tag('span','UserList',['style'=>'color:red']);
        $this->content->text  .= ' block!';
        $this->content->footer = "Τotal Users: $user->total_users";
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

So how can I set a name different from `[[pluginame]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a file within your plugin called lang/en/block_NAMEOFYOURPLUGIN.php and make sure it has at least the following:

```
<?php
$string['pluginname'] = 'The name of my plugin';
```

You will need to the purge the site caches or bump your plugin version number, in order for the name to appear.

Comment: Be sure to follow Moodle guidelines regarding the code of your block.
For example auth plugins require setting `authtype` property in the class constructor:

    function __construct() {
        $this->authtype = 'myauthpluginname';
    }

Without it plugin displays its name as "[[pluginname]]" even if there is an appropriate language file.